# tfs / svn / project server / wiki on same box

Tags: svn, team-foundation-server, wiki, microsoft-project

We are in the process of setting up a new development environment for about a dozen developers in our IT department, and I've got a few questions as far as server setup goes..

We're going to be using TFS 2008 for our 6 or so .NET developers, and subversion for the half dozen CF people.

Is it ok/recommended/not recommended to have both source control repositories on the same box? We'd be setting up TFS as a single-server environment with SQL server on the same machine.

Also, some management would like to use Project Server. We've already been through a bad install of project server where it messed up our TFS sharepoint and reporting services, and I haven't had any results from google saying that anyone out there has set up Project Server and TFS on the same box. Should we install Project Server on a separate box?

We are also going to set up a 3rd party Wiki, not sure if it will be hosted in IIS or Apache.

So basically, I'm asking for overall advice on setting up this environment, separation of servers/concerns, best practices, things we definitely should not do. This is all in a virtual environment, so there's not really a limit on number of servers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help with integration of Project Server and TFS -  http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/administration/integrating-project-server-2007-and-team-foundation-server-2008-sharepoint-sites

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can classify this in a category to make a decision. This is a classic example of a scalability problem. This should not be a problem for a handful of developers accessing the resources, but depending on the size of the projects/commits/updates/branch merges etc it may cause a slowdown i the I/O speed is slow/limited. IDE subsystem may perform fine for one or two users but as soon as you start adding load, the IDE sub system may cause a bottleneck. but since you are on a virutal environment yo probably have a good hardware raid and I/O wouldnt be the problem.

So all in all, it all depends on what kind of load you are going to thru at each of the services. and if you seperate them as virtual boxes, they all still be on the same hardware, so i'd say keeping them on one machine may be a better solution...unless u plan on moving them offf to seperate hardware/virtial systems..

Bottom line - u need to say something more about typical usage of each service.

Answer (score 1):

In an environment where each service can produce a substantial load, I would definitely recommended to separate them into individual (physical) machines, mostly because the context switching can cause a lot of overhead. However, I doubt that a dozen developers can produce substantial load on any of the named services. Running them in virtual machines will definitely make your life easier when you have to scale out, but it does add to the overheads of the physical machine than runs all the VMs.
I would not recommend running IIS and Apache on the same (virtual) machine. You are just asking for trouble there.